# stopRecorder() is not working - react-native-audio-recorder-player

Tags: react-native, audio, hybrid-mobile-app, mobile-application

I'm trying to record audio in react native app using package **react-native-audio-recorder-player**. Audio recording starts successfully but keep recording even after calling *stopRecorder()*.

Tried number of solutions from gitHub but nothing helping. Here is my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import AudioRecorderPlayer from 'react-native-audio-recorder-player';

export const Recorder = () => {
 const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();

 const onStartRecord = async () => {
  await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder();
  audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener(e => {
    console.log('Recording . . . ', e.current_position);
     return;
    });
  };

 const onStopRecord = async () => {
  const audio = await audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
  audioRecorderPlayer.removeRecordBackListener();
  };

 return (
  <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'space-between'}}>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={onStartRecord}>
     <Text>Start</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>

   <TouchableOpacity onPress={onStopRecord}>
     <Text>Stop</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
 );
};
```

Even after pressing Stop, console is still getting **Recording . . .**, following is my console.

[image]

Comment: I keep getting `Error occured during initiating recorder` even when copying your component. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For this work, need to add `const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();` outside the component. So, component will look like this.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text} from 'react-native';
import AudioRecorderPlayer from 'react-native-audio-recorder-player';

const audioRecorderPlayer = new AudioRecorderPlayer();

export const Recorder = () => {
 const onStartRecord = async () => {
  await audioRecorderPlayer.startRecorder();
  audioRecorderPlayer.addRecordBackListener(e => {
    console.log('Recording . . . ', e.current_position);
     return;
    });
  };

 const onStopRecord = async () => {
  const audio = await audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
  audioRecorderPlayer.removeRecordBackListener();
  };

 return (
  <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'space-between'}}>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={onStartRecord}>
     <Text>Start</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>

   <TouchableOpacity onPress={onStopRecord}>
     <Text>Stop</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
 );
};
```

After this change, my stopRecorder is working like charm.

Comment: I faced the same issue. Above answer is helpfull for me. Thanks bro

Comment: this is working but when try to get the number of recorded sec then function is calling but not stopping recording.

Answer (score 1):

For stopping both recording and playback functionality, you can use React's **useCallback** hook to create memoized callback functions. Here's how you can structure it:

1. Stopping Playback:

If you want to stop playback, first check whether anything is currently playing. If nothing is playing, simply log a message and exit. If there is an ongoing playback, try stopping the player, remove the playback listener, and update your state.

```
const onStopPlay = React.useCallback(async () => {
    if (!isPlaying) {
        console.log("Not currently playing.");
        return;
    }
    
    try {
        await audioRecorderPlayer.stopPlayer();
        audioRecorderPlayer.removePlayBackListener();
        setIsPlaying(false);
        console.log("Stopped playback.");
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error stopping the playback:", error);
    }
}, []);
```

you can use isPlaying, audioRecorderPlayer, setIsPlaying in the **dependency []**

2. Stopping Recording:

For stopping the recording, you can directly attempt to stop the recorder, remove the record back listener, and then update your state.

```
const onStopRecord = React.useCallback(async () => {
    try {
        const result = await audioRecorderPlayer.stopRecorder();
        audioRecorderPlayer.removeRecordBackListener();
        setIsRecording(false);
        console.log("Stopped recording:", result);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error stopping the recording:", error);
    }
}, []);
```

you can use audioRecorderPlayer, setIsRecording in the **dependency []**

Remember to include dependencies like **isPlaying**, **audioRecorderPlayer**, and **setIsPlaying** in the dependency array of the **useCallback** hook for the appropriate callbacks to ensure they always reference the most recent state and props.